# Retrieve multiple result sets from a stored procedure using ObjectContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, objectcontext

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetData
   ...Parameter
AS
   SELECT 'hello' AS 'HelloColumn'
GO
```

and then I use `ObjectContext` to execute the stored procedure

```
((IOjbectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<HelloClass>("uspGetData", .... Parameter);
```

`HelloClass` just a data class

```
public class HelloClass
{
    public string HelloColumn { ... }
}
```

and I get the perfect result that I need

but now I require to add another `SELECT` in the stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetData
   ...Parameter
AS
   SELECT 'hello' AS 'HelloColumn'
   SELECT 'byebye' AS 'ByeColumn'
GO
```

Of course in real environment is more complex and doesn't only do `SELECT something`

Now I can't get the results that I require to,

I tried to do base class on the `HelloClass`

```
public class HelloClass : ByeClass
{ ... }
```

also I try to insert 2 Object set into the `ObjectContext` command

```
((IOjbectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<HelloClass,ByeClass>...
```

Is there anyway to get both results set out of the stored procedure?

Comment: No, as far as I know, EF does not support stored procedures with multiple result sets - you either need to have multiple separate stored procedures, each returning a single result set, or you need to use "raw" ADO.NET to handle these results

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is a way.

```
using (var db = new YourContext())
{
      var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedure";
      db.Database.Connection.Open();
      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      ObjectResult<HelloClass> table1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<HelloClass>(reader, "HelloClass", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
      reader.NextResult();
      ObjectResult<HelloClass2> table2 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<HelloClass2>(reader, "HelloClass2", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
}
```

for more info check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx